# Create an object from Abstract type class in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, abstract-class, xamarin.ios-binding, sightcall

In my Xamarin.iOS binding project, I have a generated class called `LSMAUsecase.g.cs`. following is the content of that class.

```
namespace SightCallBinding {
[Protocol (Name = "LSMAUsecase", WrapperType = typeof (LSMAUsecaseWrapper))]
[ProtocolMember (IsRequired = true, IsProperty = true, IsStatic = false, Name = "Name", Selector = "name", PropertyType = typeof (string), GetterSelector = "name", ArgumentSemantic = ArgumentSemantic.None)]
public interface ILSMAUsecase : INativeObject, IDisposable
{
    [Preserve (Conditional = true)]
    string Name {
        [Export ("name")]
        get;
    }   
}

internal sealed class LSMAUsecaseWrapper : BaseWrapper, ILSMAUsecase {
    [Preserve (Conditional = true)]
    public LSMAUsecaseWrapper (IntPtr handle, bool owns)
        : base (handle, owns)
    {
    }

    [BindingImpl (BindingImplOptions.GeneratedCode | BindingImplOptions.Optimizable)]
    public string Name {
        [Export ("name")]
        get {
            return NSString.FromHandle (global::ApiDefinitions.Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSend (this.Handle, Selector.GetHandle ("name")));
        }

    }

}

}

namespace SightCallBinding {
[Protocol()]
[Register("LSMAUsecase", false)]
[Model]


 public unsafe abstract partial class LSMAUsecase : NSObject, ILSMAUsecase {

    [BindingImpl (BindingImplOptions.GeneratedCode | BindingImplOptions.Optimizable)]
    [EditorBrowsable (EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    [Export ("init")]
    protected LSMAUsecase () : base (NSObjectFlag.Empty)
    {
        IsDirectBinding = false;
        InitializeHandle (global::ApiDefinitions.Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper (this.SuperHandle, global::ObjCRuntime.Selector.GetHandle ("init")), "init");
    }

    [BindingImpl (BindingImplOptions.GeneratedCode | BindingImplOptions.Optimizable)]
    [EditorBrowsable (EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    protected LSMAUsecase (NSObjectFlag t) : base (t)
    {
        IsDirectBinding = false;
    }

    [BindingImpl (BindingImplOptions.GeneratedCode | BindingImplOptions.Optimizable)]
    [EditorBrowsable (EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    protected internal LSMAUsecase (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
        IsDirectBinding = false;
    }

    [BindingImpl (BindingImplOptions.GeneratedCode | BindingImplOptions.Optimizable)]
    public abstract string Name {
        [Export ("name")]
        get; 
    }

} /* class LSMAUsecase */
}
```

I want to pass `LSMaUsecase` object to a method. But I cannot create any object from this since it is an abstract class. And I cannot even cast into LSMAUsecase type. It says, invalid cast. Is there any way to resolve this How can I pass this type of object. following is the related method in the interface.

```
    [BindingImpl(BindingImplOptions.GeneratedCode | BindingImplOptions.Optimizable)]
    [Export("sendInvitationForUsecasePhone:toPhone:withReference:andNotify:")]
    [Preserve(Conditional = true)]
    void SendInvitationForUsecasePhone(LSMAUsecase usecase, string phoneNumber, string reference, [BlockProxy(typeof(NIDActionArity2V0))] Action<LSMAPincodeStatus_t, NSString> block);
```

**UPDATE**

This is my extended class

```
public class Usecase : LSMAUsecase
{
    public override string Name { get; }
    public Usecase()
        : base()
    {

    }

}
```

Then I am getting this exception since I don't have any value for "Name"(Name is get only).

> Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name:
>   NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[LSMAHandler
>   sendInvitationForUsecasePhone:toPhone:withReference:andNotify:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x282458780

Comment: Just Create a new class that inherits from `LSMAUsecase ` and then initialize that and pass it!

Comment: @G.hakim I tried this. But I am getting an exception since the "Name" is null. It is read only. And I cannot caste Dictionary<string, object> into my class type. Is there any way to sort out these 2 issues?

Comment: Did you call the base constructor?

Comment: @G.hakim Did you mean LSMAUsecase constructor?

Comment: call the base implementation in your extended/derived class!!

Comment: @G.hakim I updated the question with the new class I created and the mentioned exception is coming since I don't have value for Name property.